# use a single DB for multi-location rails app

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I plan to offer a web REST based services (all dynamic content, no static stuff) to both Asia and US clients and it appears that the network latency is pretty bad for an Asian customer connecting to US server, my current server is hosted on RackSpace cloud, it runs both app server and MySQL DB - so I plan to set up another Rails server in Asian, but now what is the best practice for the RDB?

option 1 is for two Rails server connect to its own local database, but then I have two separate set of DB (include user registration DB) and user registered in US won't see user registered in Asia.

option 2 is two Rails server connect to the same MySQL DB, hopefully add some SQL caching (Memcache) in the middle between Rails and DB, but I am not sure the performance of this setup

can anyone suggest which option to take, and is there any best practice in adopting option 2?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could go with option 1, and setup a master-slave setup ([MySQL replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html)). So each server is connected to a local db, but the one in Asia would be the slave syncing with the master db in the US. The latency will still be an issue. You may have to try both options in test environments, and see what is best for you, and most maintainable.

Comment: thanks Carl. It seems I can only get one direction sync in this master-slave mode, so if I set US DB as master,then I cannot really save new data to the Asian DB server, is that right?